# Parse typescript file on the cli and remove an element

Tags: typescript, awk, sed, command-line-interface, jq

Hey peeps I am looking for a way to parse a typescript file and easily remove and element from the embedded json object within a couple of codegen types.

Would be pretty easy with the likes of `jq` however that doesnt work for a typescript file with an embedded object like this I found.

Feel like this could be done with sed or awk however I havent had anyluck removing the whole `{..}' element.

before:

```
export type Pools = {
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "hydra_liquidity_pools",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "poolState",
      "type": {
        "kind": "struct",
        "fields": [
          ...  
          {
            "name": "reserved",
            "type": {
              "defined": "Reserve"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
...
}
```

after:

```
export type Pools = {
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "hydra_liquidity_pools",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "poolState",
      "type": {
        "kind": "struct",
        "fields": [
          ...  
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have jq take the whole typscript (using `-Rs`), extract and manipulate the JSON part (using `fromjson` and `tojson`), and write it back (using `-r`). This requires you to know and model the typescript part, and to condone the altered formatting of the JSON part (basically all in one line).

Example using `capture`:

```sh
jq -Rsr '
  capture("(?<ts>export type Pools = )(?<json>.*)";"m")
  | .json |= (fromjson | (.) | tojson)
  | .ts + .json
'
```

```
export type Pools = {"version":"0.1.0","name":"hydra_liquidity_pools","accounts":[{"name":"poolState","type":{"kind":"struct","fields":[{"name":"reserved","type":{"defined":"Reserve"}}]}}]}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/s4jTp6i3YY)

Adjust `(?<ts>export type Pools = )` to whatever should be captured as the typescript part using a regex, and change `(.)` to whatever you want to do with the JSON part using jq.

Comment: Sorry this doesnt quite explain how do I remove the ```[{"name":"reserved","type":{"defined":"Reserve"}}]``` element with this syntax?

Comment: @utx0_ You said the jq part "would be pretty easy", that's why I left it out. Also, you didn't really specify what exactlly to delete. Maybe **all items** within `field` for **all items** of `accounts` (`del(.accounts[].type.fields[])` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rvTEs0BZWs))? Or maybe only **items that match** `.name == "reserved"` in the **first item** of `accounts` (`del(.accounts[0].type.fields[] | select(.name == "reserved"))` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/B8HYcjwTKv))? -- Just two out of many possibilities that all match your sample output. If it's neither of the above, please specify.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can apply `jq` by extracting the json string. Let me modify
the provided TypeScript file to contain a valid json string.

`file.ts`:

```
export type Pools = {
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "hydra_liquidity_pools",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "poolState",
      "type": {
        "kind": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "foo": "bar"
          },
          {
            "name": "reserved",
            "type": {
              "defined": "Reserve"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then try:

```
lval=$(sed -nE 's/(.*= ).*/\1/p' < file.ts)             # extract "export type Pools = "
echo "$lval" "$(sed "s/$lval//" file.ts | jq 'del(.accounts[].type.fields[] | select (.name == "reserved"))')"
```

Output:

```
export type Pools =  {
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "hydra_liquidity_pools",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "poolState",
      "type": {
        "kind": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "foo": "bar"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```